# Replace values in specific column of dataframe using dictionary dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm having a dataframe with 22 columns where 17th column are city names stated in german. I do have another dataframe with 2 columns, in 1st - citynames in german, column 2 -in english. How do i replace values in column 17 in first dataframe using second "dictionary" dataframe?

```r
ticket_id <- c(1,3,4,5)
depart_city <- c(Lemberg, Köln, Düsseldorf, Lemberg)
price <- c(20,25,22,21)
tickets <- data.frame(ticket,id, depart_city, price)

de <- c(Lemberg, Düsseldorf, Köln)
eng <- c(Lviv, Duesseldorf, COlogne)
dict <- data.frame(eng,de)
```

These are the examples of 2 dataframes.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your data sets, you can use `dput`

Comment: You will want to do a left join. Look into either `merge()` or `dplyr::left_join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `factor` to set the levels and labels of the column of interest:

```r
#before change
tickets$depart_city
#> [1] "Lemberg"    "Köln"       "Düsseldorf" "Lemberg"

#how to change
tickets$depart_city <- as.character(
  factor(
    tickets$depart_city, 
    levels = dict$de, 
    labels = dict$eng
    )
  )

#after change
tickets$depart_city
#> [1] "Lviv"        "COlogne"     "Duesseldorf" "Lviv"
```